# Read HKU VB and VBA Program settings

Tags: vb6, vbscript

How do I read a particular vb program settings or registry entry from the registry of the key "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1390067357-1965331169-725345543-1003\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings".A standardized way to read as the part after hikey_users and before software changes with the pc used,but the vb programs do write  perfectly at the right place.Is there some variable that defines the registry key location ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB6 has built-in functions for manipulating the registry, like [GetSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445018%28VS.60%29.aspx). These functions [use registry keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155731%28office.10%29.aspx) underneath `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings`

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1390067357-1965331169-725345543-1003\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings` is just another path to the same set of keys: the long string in the middle identifies the current user by their ID, rather than just saying "the current user".

So the answer is:

- If you are using VB6, just use [GetSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445018%28VS.60%29.aspx).
- If you are using VBScript, use [WshShell.RegRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd%28VS.85%29.aspx) and work on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings`. Example code in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd%28VS.85%29.aspx).